# extjs 4.x Chart, axes and series label

Tags: extjs, series, axes

Its just simple bar chart, 
type: category at bottom and type:numeric to the left

fields: rate , type:numeric, position: left, minimum: 85 , maximum: 100

I get value of less than 85 , then the one's label is missing(doesnt appear) logically.
how do I get the label at the bottom with the value less than 85 ?
minimum at 85 is a condition.

Thanjs in advance

Comment: Please post your code (preferably in MCVE format, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help.

Comment: post you code with your chart image it will help people to understand your problem